# Easy way to insert rows of dataTable to database

Tags: c#, insert, datatable

I have a dataTable a little different with additional some external fields from the database's table. Is there any way to inser these rows without looping in the rows?

If my datatable would be the same with database table could I insert it quickly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can do this using below code

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConsoleApplication3.Properties.Settings.daasConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
  cn.Open();

  using (SqlBulkCopy copy = new SqlBulkCopy(cn))
  {
    copy.ColumnMappings.Add(0, 0);
    copy.ColumnMappings.Add(1, 1);
    copy.ColumnMappings.Add(2, 2);
    copy.ColumnMappings.Add(3, 3);
    copy.ColumnMappings.Add(4, 4);

    copy.DestinationTableName = "tNorthwind";

    copy.WriteToServer(dt);
  }
}
```

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/DataTableToDataBase.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure from your question if the schemas are the same. If they are then you can simply create an Adapter and call update. An example using ODBC...

```
public void Update(DataTable table)
{
OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(...);
OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM TABLENAME", connection);

OdbcCommandBuilder builder = new OdbcCommandBuilder(adapter);
adapter.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand();
adapter.InsertCommand = builder.GetInsertCommand();
adapter.DeleteCommand = builder.GetDeleteCommand();

adapter.Update(table);
}
```